# Optimizing SELECT query performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization, view

I have a `SELECT` statement that runs really slow, it's holding back our night process.

The query is: (Please don't comment about the implicit join syntax, this is automatically generated by Informatica that runs this code) :

```
SELECT *
  FROM STG_DIM_CRM_CASES,V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH,stg_scd_customers_key
 WHERE STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.CRM_CASE_ID = V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH.CASE_ID(+)
   AND STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.account_number = stg_scd_customers_key.account_number(+)
   and STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.Case_Create_Date between  stg_scd_customers_key.start_date(+) and  stg_scd_customers_key.end_date(+)
```

**edit**: The actual query selects only `account_number,start_date,end_date` and one other column which is not indexed.

Tables info :

STG_DIM_CRM_CASES

```
Index - (Account_Number,Case_Create_Date)
size - 270k records.
```

stg_scd_customers_key

```
Index - Account_Number,Start_Date,End_Date
Partitioned - End_Date
Size - 500 million records.
```

V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH(View) -

```
select  t.case_id
from crm_ps_rc_case t, dim_crm_cases x
where t.case_id=x.crm_case_id;
```

dim_crm_cases -

```
Indexed - (crm_case_id)
Size - 100 million .
```

crm_ps_rc_case -

```
Size - 270k records
```

**Edit** - If it wasn't clear, the view returns 270k records .

The query without the join to `stg_scd` is taking seconds, looks like it is the part that causing the performance issues, the view runs in seconds too although it is being joined to a 100 Million records table. Right now the query is taking somewhere between 12 to 30 minutes, depends how busy our sources are.

Here is the EXECUTION PLAN :

```
6   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                             |  3278K|  1297M|   559K  (4)| 02:10:37 |       |       |        |      |            |
7   |   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                 |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
8   |   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)           | :TQ10003                    |  3278K|  1297M|   559K  (4)| 02:10:37 |       |       |  Q1,03 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
9   |*  3 |    HASH JOIN OUTER              |                             |  3278K|  1297M|   559K  (4)| 02:10:37 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
10  |   4 |     PX RECEIVE                  |                             | 29188 |    10M| 50662   (5)| 00:11:50 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
11  |   5 |      PX SEND HASH               | :TQ10002                    | 29188 |    10M| 50662   (5)| 00:11:50 |       |       |  Q1,02 | P->P | HASH       |
12  |*  6 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER     |                             | 29188 |    10M| 50662   (5)| 00:11:50 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
13  |   7 |        BUFFER SORT              |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWC |            |
14  |   8 |         PX RECEIVE              |                             | 29188 |   370K| 50575   (5)| 00:11:49 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
15  |   9 |          PX SEND BROADCAST      | :TQ10000                    | 29188 |   370K| 50575   (5)| 00:11:49 |       |       |        | S->P | BROADCAST  |
16  |  10 |           VIEW                  | V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH | 29188 |   370K| 50575   (5)| 00:11:49 |       |       |        |      |            |
17  |* 11 |            HASH JOIN            |                             | 29188 |   399K| 50575   (5)| 00:11:49 |       |       |        |      |            |
18  |  12 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL   | CRM_PS_RC_CASE              | 29188 |   199K|   570   (1)| 00:00:08 |       |       |        |      |            |
19  |  13 |             INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| DIM_CRM_CASES$1PK           |   103M|   692M| 48894   (3)| 00:11:25 |       |       |        |      |            |
20  |  14 |        PX BLOCK ITERATOR        |                             | 29188 |    10M|    87   (2)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWC |            |
21  |  15 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL       | STG_DIM_CRM_CASES           | 29188 |    10M|    87   (2)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
22  |  16 |     BUFFER SORT                 |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
23  |  17 |      PX RECEIVE                 |                             |   515M|    14G|   507K  (3)| 01:58:28 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
24  |  18 |       PX SEND HASH              | :TQ10001                    |   515M|    14G|   507K  (3)| 01:58:28 |       |       |        | S->P | HASH       |
25  |  19 |        PARTITION RANGE ALL      |                             |   515M|    14G|   507K  (3)| 01:58:28 |     1 |  2982 |        |      |            |
26  |  20 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL       | STG_SCD_CUSTOMERS_KEY       |   515M|    14G|   507K  (3)| 01:58:28 |     1 |  2982 |        |      |            |
27  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28   
29  Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
30  ---------------------------------------------------
31   
32     3 - access("STG_DIM_CRM_CASES"."ACCOUNT_NUMBER"="STG_SCD_CUSTOMERS_KEY"."ACCOUNT_NUMBER"(+))
33         filter("STG_DIM_CRM_CASES"."CASE_CREATE_DATE">="STG_SCD_CUSTOMERS_KEY"."START_DATE"(+) AND 
34                "STG_DIM_CRM_CASES"."CASE_CREATE_DATE"<="STG_SCD_CUSTOMERS_KEY"."END_DATE"(+))
35     6 - access("STG_DIM_CRM_CASES"."CRM_CASE_ID"="V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH"."CASE_ID"(+))
36    11 - access("T"."CASE_ID"="X"."CRM_CASE_ID")
```

**Notes:** Adding indexes may be an issue, depends on the index. This is not the only place this tables are being used, so indexes may interfere with other commands(Inserts mostly) on these tables.

I've also tried adding a filter on `stg_scd` and excluding all the dates smaller than the minimum date in `Table_Cases`, but that didn't help because it filtered only 1 year of records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would consider that indexes are your best bet.

Comment: It is full plan? I don't see Table_Cases and stg_scd.

Comment: Also I see at least one blocked operation 'BUFFER SORT'. It would be helpful if you post full plan. There can be more than one DFO tree.

Comment: Yes, this is the full plan.

Comment: Have you considered -  using normal join. Then use abother flow to add whatever missing. This may be little fast not significant. Question - when you say Index - Account_Number,Start_Date,End_Date - do you have individual index or single index for all ?

Comment: It's a single index for all 3 columns. Yea, I considered it, but the problems seems to be with the join to `stg_scd` , so even if I'd split it to two flows, the join will still take time. @Koushik

Comment: @sagi It looks like some lines are missing from the execution plan.  Some of the tables aren't mentioned.  It seems like there must be at least one more line - the last HASH JOIN only has one child operation but it should have two.  Also, with huge tables like this, the degree of parallelism might be important.  You might want to use SQL monitoring to find the requested and allocated DOP - something like `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'xyz') from dual;`.  That would also help find the estimated and actual cardinalities, and time per operation.

Comment: @sagi - Thanks for replying. Can you check if you have individual index on those columns rather than single index for all. Also you can check chnaging between clause  "and Table_Cases.Case_Create_Date >= stg_scd.start_date(+) and Table_Cases.Case_Create_Date<= stg_scd.end_date(+)". Because stg_scd has an index on END_DATE date.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: May be I don't understand smt but in your explain plan I see view V_Cases_Dwh and table CRM_PS_RC_CASE. In you description I don't see any mention about table CRM_PS_RC_CASE and for what query this explain plan(The query when your join Table_Cases,V_Cases_Dwh,stg_scd)?. (Please include @username when answer. Last time you for some reason have forgotten do that and I remember about this question tool late)

Comment: @sagi, +1 on all of Evgeniy's questions; and even beyond that, the title row is missing from the explain plan to describe what the content is. How many rows does the query typically return? Do you care about seeing the entire result set, or is there some way you can restrict table_cases up front? Have you reviewed optimizer statistics profile on all base tables?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the tables names in the question, `ps_rc_case` is `crm_cases` . The explain plan is for the first query provided. @EvgeniyK.

Comment: The query typically returns 300k records, `table_cases` is the lead table here. I am interested in the entire result set.. I didn't find any way to retrict any of the tables in a way that improves the current query, but any suggestions will be appreciated. I didn't understand the last thing about the  statistics, why do I need to review it ? @PeterM.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. I'm sorry, that wasn't the full plan. I've updated the question with the entire plan and fixed the names.

Comment: @sagi, Oracle will use statistics to choose the best query plan. If all's well, it should be collecting them automatically across your data. You would just want to check if they are complete and recent. A good sanity check is that the expected number of rows Oracle foresees in its query plan somewhat matches the actual number of rows returned. In this case, it's only different by a factor of 2, so it's in the ball park. If it was out by a factor of 10 or more, it would point to some stats being wrong.

Comment: Well, I've already ran statistics on all the tables involved so they will be complete and recent, so I doubt that's the case. Unless there is another thing I don't know about? :) @PeterM.

Comment: Is there any chance of replacing (manually or otherwise) the query with modern join syntax?

Comment: Yes, manually, not really recommended. Why does it matter? @bohemian

Comment: I've noted in the past poor choices by the engine when joining to a view..  What I believed was happening is the engine effectively did a cross join first and then applied the join criteria as limiting criteria;  meaning it did the cross join, then filtered out all the results, when what we really want it to do is reduce the base data set of each table before resolving the join through the indexes.  To resolve I eliminated the view and the engine was able to select a more optimal plan.  The joining of the view (100m+) results to the 500m records in stg_scd_customers_key seems to be the problem

Comment: If you haven't already (and the problem is not solved yet), you may want to ask the same question on OTN. There are a few good people there who don't seem to ever touch SO. You would need to post your question in full there, but you could also include a link to this thread so they can see the discussion so far (if they are so inclined). Good luck!

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: What happens when you select from stg_scd_customers_key  only account_number,start_date and end_date . I think that the select * prevent the index on stg_scd_customers_key to be used

Comment: Actually I do select only these columns(with the customer_key field which is the required column from this table) @Mottor

Answer (score 3):

What I believe to be happening is the engine is having to resolve the 100m+ records from view join to 500m records BEFORE it applies limiting criteria (thus it creates a cross join and even if it can use indexes that's a lot of records to generate then parse.  So even though you wrote it as an outer join, the engine isn't able to processes it that way (I don't know why)

So at a minimum 100m*500m = 50,000m  that's a lot of data to generate and then parse/limit.

By eliminating the view, the engine may be better able to optimize and use the indexes thus eliminating the need for the 50,000m record join.

Areas where I would focus my time in troubleshooting:

- Eliminate the view just to remove it as a potential overhead issue.
- Recognize no tie between stg_scd_customers_key and V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH exists.  This means the engine may be doing a cross join BEFORE the results of 
  STG_DIM_CRM_CASES to stg_scd_customers_key have been resolved.

CONSIDER eliminating the view, or using an inline view

Eliminating the view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM STG_DIM_CRM_CASES 
      ,crm_ps_rc_case t
      ,dim_crm_cases x 
      ,stg_scd_customers_key
 WHERE t.case_id=x.crm_case_id
   AND STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.CRM_CASE_ID = t.CASE_ID(+)
   AND STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.account_number = stg_scd_customers_key.account_number(+)
   AND STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.Case_Create_Date 
       between  stg_scd_customers_key.start_date(+) and stg_scd_customers_key.end_date(+)
```

using an inline view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM STG_DIM_CRM_CASES 
  (select  t.case_id
   from crm_ps_rc_case t, dim_crm_cases x
   where t.case_id=x.crm_case_id) V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH
      ,stg_scd_customers_key
 WHERE STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.CRM_CASE_ID = V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH.CASE_ID(+)
   AND STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.account_number = stg_scd_customers_key.account_number(+)
   AND STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.Case_Create_Date 
       between  stg_scd_customers_key.start_date(+) and stg_scd_customers_key.end_date(+)
```

As to why: 
 - http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_hints_views.htm

While order of the where clause SHOULDN'T matter consider:  On the off chase the engine is executing in the order listed, limiting the 500m down and then adding the supplemental data from the view would logically be faster.

```
SELECT *
  FROM STG_DIM_CRM_CASES,stg_scd_customers_key,V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH
 WHERE STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.account_number = stg_scd_customers_key.account_number(+)
   and STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.Case_Create_Date between  stg_scd_customers_key.start_date(+) and  stg_scd_customers_key.end_date(+)
   and STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.CRM_CASE_ID = V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH.CASE_ID(+)
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough in the question, the view returns 270k records, and I believe the view is being processed by the optimizer before the outer query.. I'll give it a try when I'll get to work. Thanks for the answer .

Comment: maths: 100m*500m = 50,000mm = 50,000,000,000m (assuming m is million)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in scanning all partitions:

> 18 |       PX SEND HASH              | :TQ10001                    | 
>   515M|    14G|   507K  (3)| 01:58:28 |       |       |        | S->P |
>   HASH       | 25  |  19 |        PARTITION RANGE ALL      |
>   |   515M|    14G|   507K  (3)| 01:58:28 |     1 |  2982 |        |
>   |            | 26  |  20 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL       |
>   STG_SCD_CUSTOMERS_KEY       |   515M|    14G|

It happens because you are using left join to this table. Can you select 1 partition using bind variable? What is partition key?
I don't see hint for parallel but according to you plan it uses parallel. Is there parallel degree on any object level? Can you remove parallel and post explain plan without parallel please?

Comment: Nope, no parallel hint anywhere .. I don't know why it says so. Yea, it is a problem, but I do need to use all partitions, at least almost all of them.

Comment: @sagi You can check the objects for a parallel setting with a statement like this: `select degree, dba_tables.* from dba_tables where trim(degree) <> '1';`.  It's also possible that parallelism is forced at the session level, or automated at the system level.  You can override the parallelism with a hint like `/*+ no_parallel */`.

Comment: But shouldn't this possibility speed up the process? All partitions are running parallel. @jonheller

Comment: @sagi  Possibly but there are many ways that parallelism can go wrong.  For example, if the indexes aren't parallel but the table is, Oracle may decide to use a parallel full table scan instead of a single-threaded index access.  Maybe the parallel FTS is 10% faster but uses 64 threads - a slight improvement for the query but horribly inefficient for the system.  If other queries are doing the same thing it can quickly bring the whole system to a crawl.  It is easy to break a system with unexpected parallel queries - if you have found one of them, you should probably check for others.

Comment: @sagi It looks like you might be in a situation where there are no magical access paths to make this run in seconds.  300K index reads could be expensive, especially if the index clustering factor is high.  (That is, if the data is ordered randomly and thus requires reading 300K blocks from the table.)  But even if you're stuck with full table scans there may be ways to improve performance - modify the DOP, try to reduce other system activity, check the raw I/O read performance for system issues, etc.

Comment: @JonHeller May be I am wrong but for me scanninng full table(with such many partitions) it isn't good decision for this query and I think that only partition prunning would help query.

Comment: @sagi, can you please share partitioning clause please? If you say that you need to scan ALL partitions you have to be ready that this query will be running slower and slower (assuming your application adds them regularly).  But without seeing table DDL I can't suggest any particular solutions.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. There are many times when a full table scan outperforms an index - it depends mostly on how much faster multi-block reads are compared to single-block reads, the index clustering factor, and the percentage of records that are read.  All three of which are highly dependent on the environment and data.  There's no telling which is better without either much more information about the environment or some testing.

Comment: I'm not sure how much control he has over his SQL.  If he can change it, it sounds like he could compute the minimum value of `Case_Create_Date` in a few seconds.  Then, he could add a clause in the join condition to the 500 million row table to say `AND end_date >= that_min_value`.  But it's unclear how many partitions that will prune.

Comment: Wrong. PARTITON RANGE just didn't manage to filter out any of the partitions. That means that results exist in all partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the view, which I suspect is completely executing and returning all rows *before* conditions are being applied.

The overall effect of the view is to add the column `CASE_ID` that is not null if `CRM_CASE_ID` is found in it, null otherwise. I've replaced the view with two direct joins and a CASE expression. By replacing the convenience of the view with logic, you can join directly to each table in it and so avoid one level of join depth.

Try running this version of the query:

```
SELECT
  a.*, b.*, c.*,
  CASE WHEN t.case_id is not null and X.case_id is not null then t.case_id END CASE_ID
FROM STG_DIM_CRM_CASES a
LEFT JOIN crm_ps_rc_case t
  ON t.case_id = a.CRM_CASE_ID
LEFT JOIN dim_crm_cases x
  ON x.crm_case_id = a.CRM_CASE_ID
LEFT JOIN V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH b
  ON a.CRM_CASE_ID = b.CASE_ID
LEFT JOIN stg_scd_customers_key c
  ON a.account_number = c.account_number
 and a.Case_Create_Date between c.start_date and  stg_scd_customers_key.end_date
```

If you replace `a.*, b.*, c.*` with only the exact columns you actually need, you'll get a speed up because there's simply less data to return. If you also put indexes on looked-up keys plus all the columns you actually select (a *covering* index), you will speed it up considerably, because index-only access can be used.

You should verify there are indexes in all joined-to columns as a minimum.

Comment: Actually the view by it self is very fast, so I doubt this will solve the issue, but I'll try it when I'll get to work. Only the needed columns are being selected, I just didn't write them because they don't matter. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sagi the view could be fast by itself, but could make the other parts of the query very slow, take a llok at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Oracle really only has two ways to get the rows it needs from `stg_scd_customers_key`.  Either (A) it does a single `FULL SCAN` of that table and then filters out the rows it doesn't want or else (B) it does 270,000 index lookups, at 3 to maybe 5 logical I/Os each (depending on the height of your index), plus another 1 logical I/O to actually read the block from the table.

Given the multiblock read and other optimizations available with a `FULL SCAN`, and based on your table statistics, Oracle's optimizer is guessing that the `FULL SCAN` would be faster.  And there's a good chance that it's right.

What you need to do is give Oracle a better option.

If you cannot use materialized views where you are, a good "poor man's" materialized view is something called a covering index.  Now, that's not reasonable for your query, since you do a `SELECT *`.  But do you really need every column from `stg_scd_customers_key`?

If you can pare down the list of columns you get from `stg_scd_customers_key`, you can create an index that (A) starts with `account_number`, `start_date`, and `end_date` and (B) includes all the other columns you need to select.

For example:

```
SELECT stg_im_crm_cases.*, V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH.*, stg_scd_customers_key.column_1, stg_scd_customers_key.column_2
  FROM STG_DIM_CRM_CASES,V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH,stg_scd_customers_key
 WHERE STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.CRM_CASE_ID = V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH.CASE_ID(+)
   AND STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.account_number = stg_scd_customers_key.account_number(+)
   and STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.Case_Create_Date between  stg_scd_customers_key.start_date(+) and  stg_scd_customers_key.end_date(+)
```

If you could make that your query, and create an index on stg_scd_customers_key (account_number, start_date, end_date, column_1, column_2), then you will have given Oracle a better alternative.  Now it can read the index alone, instead of the table.

With tables that big, there are no guarantees until you try it.  But covering indexes are often just what the doctor ordered.  (All the usual caveats about new indexes apply of course).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I commented about the columns selection in the comments, I forgot to erite it in the question. I actually select only the desired columns(account_number,start_date,end_date) which are indexed and one other column which is not. I can't add indexes on this specific table as it is being used somewhere else with huge inserts..

Comment: Option C: A fast full index scan on an index covering Account_Number, Start_Date, and End_Date. ?

Answer (score 1):

some considerations:

**1) INDEX**
`crm_ps_rc_case` has no index on `case_id` this is a problem, you are joining 270k <-> 100m with HASH JOIN (not good)

**2) SELECTED COLUMNS**
the view `V_CRM_CASE_ID_EXISTS_IN_DWH` selects `t.case_id` but it should select `x.crm_case_id` instead, at least, until you do not resolve indexing of `t.case_id`. This will spread HASH JOIN over all your execution plan.. (not good)

**3) BETWEEN**
range joining/filtering is always a problem, especially on large tables but you could restrict the problem adding conditions on range. let me explain, try to add these conditions to your `WHERE` clause:

```
AND stg_scd_customers_key.end_date =  (
       SELECT min(r.end_date)
       FROM stg_scd_customers_key r
       WHERE  r.end_date >= STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.Case_Create_Date
)
AND stg_scd_customers_key.start_date =  (
       SELECT max(r.start_date)
       FROM stg_scd_customers_key r
       WHERE  r.start_date <= STG_DIM_CRM_CASES.Case_Create_Date
)
```

yes, it will calculate 270k * 2 subqueries, but the final join will work on much less recs limiting IO operations (it should be better)

**4) INDEX COLUMN ORDER**
there are conflicting reports if it does, or if it does not matter, but in my experience.. it does.
It could be only a minor improvement but you can try to modify the index on `stg_scd_customers_key` inverting the order of `Start_Date` and `End_Date`, in my experience I have found it more efficient for range filtering to have the upper bound before the lower bound in the index.