# Mysql query optimization on multiple table join

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Is there a way to optimize this mysql query

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM cm_stream a 
INNER JOIN cm_courses b ON a.stream_id = b.stream 
INNER JOIN cm_institute_courses c ON b.course_id = c.course 
INNER JOIN cm_institute d ON d.institute_id = c.institute 
WHERE a.path = 'engineering' 
GROUP BY c.institute
```

This query taking 0.14s or more to execute and i want to optimize the time.

EXPLAIN FOR SAME QUERY

[image]

INDEX DETAILS

d Table

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`institute_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cm_institute_unique` (`path`),
  KEY `importance` (`importance`),
  KEY `cover` (`cover`),
  KEY `logo` (`logo`),
  KEY `logo_2` (`logo`,`cover`,`importance`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `abbreviation` (`abbreviation`),
  KEY `name_2` (`name`,`abbreviation`),
  KEY `path` (`path`,`institute_id`)
```

c Table

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`institute_course_id`),
  KEY `course_key` (`course`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `institute` (`institute`,`course`),
  KEY `cm_institute_cours_idx_institute_active` (`institute`,`active`),
  KEY `institute_2` (`institute`,`course`)
```

b Table

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `path` (`path`),
  KEY `program` (`program`,`stream`),
  KEY `stream` (`stream`,`course_id`),
```

a Table

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`stream_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `path` (`path`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `cm_stream_idx_name_stream_id` (`name`,`stream_id`),
  KEY `active_2` (`active`,`name`),
  KEY `path_2` (`path`,`stream_id`)
```

Comment: I see no reason for `GROUP BY c.institute` ... why do you have this at the end of your query?

Comment: without GROUP BY c.institute i m getting duplicate rows

Comment: Just use `SELECT DISTINCT d.*` in this case.

Comment: Seleting data is not my concern actually my concern is this query taking 0.14s or more to execute and i want to optimize the time.

Comment: It _is_ your concern, because until you fix these problems it makes no sense to try to optimize the query.

Comment: And, just to get an idea, try to read [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191623/how-to-optimize-queries-in-a-database-the-basics), or [Optimizing SELECT query performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613118/optimizing-select-query-performance)

Comment: Yes i understant and even using DISTINCT is not optimising on time i tried it too.

Comment: Run AN Explain SELECT ... and see which indexes are used

Comment: I have updated question and added screenshot of explain

Answer (score 1):

Since you are selecting only from `cm_institute`, an alternative way would be with `EXISTS` which sometimes performs better than joins.
Also there is no need for `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM cm_institute d
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM cm_stream a 
  INNER JOIN cm_courses b ON a.stream_id = b.stream 
  INNER JOIN cm_institute_courses c ON b.course_id = c.course 
  WHERE a.path = 'engineering' AND d.institute_id = c.institute
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For many-to-many mappings, the indexes are probably the performance problem.

You need *only* these indexes:

```
 # Basic for many_to_many table:
 PRIMARY KEY(course, institute),
 INDEX(institute, course)
 # Extras for your application:
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `cm_institute_cours_idx_institute_active` (`institute`,`active`),
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Also, these indexes:

```
a:  INDEX(path, stream_id)
b:  INDEX(stream,  course_id)
d:  INDEX(institute_id)  -- unless that is the PK
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: I added index details of all tables in updated question.

Comment: @Htesh - Thanks.  I see about 7 redundant indexes.  Note that `INDEX(a)` can/should be dropped when the table also has `INDEX(a,b)`.  On the other hand, `INDEX(a,b)` is unnecessary when you also have `UNIQUE(a)` (2 cases)

Comment: @Htesh - I updated my recommendations for `c` based on `active` indexes.  After changing c's indexes, you should notice a difference the `EXPLAIN`.  It will look minor, but it will probably give a noticeable performance boost.